# XSLT with CSS won't applay

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

Hey folks I'm struggeling to get my CSS within an XSL file working properly. The CSS won't apply to the HTML which is generated from the XML File:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="children" match="Person" use="@ChildOf" />

<xsl:template match="/Tree">
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="TreeStyle.css" type="text/css"/></head><body>
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Person[@ChildOf=0]"/>
    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Person">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="@FirstName" />
    </li>
    <xsl:variable name="children" select="key('children', @ID)" />
    <xsl:if test="$children">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$children" />
        </ul>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

CSS:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

        .tree ul {
            padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
    
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
            transition: all 0.5s;
        }

        .tree li {
            float: left; text-align: center;
            list-style-type: none;
            position: relative;
            padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
    
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
            transition: all 0.5s;
        }

        /*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

        .tree li::before, .tree li::after{
            content: '';
            position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
            border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
            width: 50%; height: 45px;
            z-index: -1;
        }
        .tree li::after{
            right: auto; left: 50%;
            border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        /*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
        any siblings*/
        .tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
            display: none;
        }

        /*Remove space from the top of single children*/
        .tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

        /*Remove left connector from first child and 
        right connector from last child*/
        .tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
            border: 0 none;
        }
        /*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
        .tree li:last-child::before{
            border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
            
            -webkit-transform: translateX(1px);
            -moz-transform: translateX(1px);
            transform: translateX(1px);
            
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
            -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
            border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
        }
        .tree li:first-child::after{
            border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
        }

        /*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
        .tree ul ul::before{
            content: '';
            position: absolute; top: -12px; left: 50%;
            border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
            width: 0; height: 32px;
            z-index: -1;
        }

        .tree li a{
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #666;
            font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
            font-size: 11px;
            display: inline-block;
            background: white;
    
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
            transition: all 0.5s;
        }
        .tree li a+a {
            margin-left: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .tree li a+a::before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
            top: 50%; left: -21px; 
            width: 20px;
        }

        /*Time for some hover effects*/
        /*We will apply the hover effect the lineage of the element also*/
        .tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover~ul li a {
            background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
        }
        /*Connector styles on hover*/
        .tree li a:hover~ul li::after, 
        .tree li a:hover~ul li::before, 
        .tree li a:hover~ul::before, 
        .tree li a:hover~ul ul::before
        {
            border-color: #94a0b4;
        }
```

What is the reason the CSS isn't applied correctly to the generated HTML?

Comment: *"What is the reason the CSS isn't applied correctly to the generated HTML?"* - I could imagine that it is because literally not a single one of the class names in the CSS exist in the HTML that your XSLT produces?

Comment: What is the source HTML? An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: Check css path `href="TreeStyle.css"` may not be correct. Also check the caps

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, your css requires a class named **tree** at a parent level above the `<ul`> and `<li>` tags. So consider adding `class="tree"` to your `<body>` tag.

```
<body class="tree">
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Person[@ChildOf=0]"/>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Alternatively, wrap a `<div class="tree">` tag around lists.

```
<body>
  <div class="tree">
     <ul>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="Person[@ChildOf=0]"/>
     </ul>
  </div> 
</body>
```

Even still, remove any **tree** reference in css and the `<ul>` and `<li>` should be styled accordingly but all will follow the same rules.